# Program still running after return 0; with SDL_Renderer

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm doing Lazy Foo's tutorial on SDL (I'm using SDL2-2.0.9), and at the texture rendering part I encountered the following problem: the program compiles and runs as expected, no issue here, but when I close the window, the console doesn't close and the process continues running, so I have to close the console separately.

When I tried to debug it, I found out that the program indeed leaves the main cycle and reaches the "return 0" line in the main function successfully, but then it just hangs like that until I close the console.

The issue is only present when I use the SDL renderer with any option other than SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE. If I use SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE - the program closes as expected. With other options it stays at "return 0" running other threads (crypt32.dll, ntdll.dll and nvd3dum, in this order in the thread view, meaning that the process is stuck in crypt32).

I'm aware that my main function is not the "real main" as it has been hijacked by SDL, so exit(0) works fine as an ad-hoc solution. But I want to know, why exactly does that happen and is there any other way to fix this, so that I don't have to use exit(0) ?

Here is an example (simplified) code, which demonstrates this issue for me:

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    SDL_Window *win = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = NULL;
    SDL_Texture *bitmapTex = NULL;
    SDL_Surface *bitmapSurface = NULL;
    int width = 640, height = 480;

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        printf("Could not initialize SDL");
        return 1;
    }

    win = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, width, height, 0);

    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    bitmapSurface = SDL_LoadBMP("res/x.bmp");
    bitmapTex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, bitmapSurface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(bitmapSurface);

    bool quit = false;
    while (!quit) {
        SDL_Event e;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0) {
            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                quit = true;
            }
        }

        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, bitmapTex, NULL, NULL);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    SDL_DestroyTexture(bitmapTex);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);

    SDL_Quit();

    printf("REACHED RETURN 0");
    return 0;

}
```

Works as intended, but after closing the window I see "REACHED RETURN 0" printed in console and that's it, the console stays there. The code can be simplified further, the issue will be present as long as there is an instance of SDL_Renderer created.

UPD: The callstack during the hanging:

```
>   ntdll.dll!_NtWaitForMultipleObjects@20()    
    KernelBase.dll!_WaitForMultipleObjectsEx@20()   
    crypt32.dll!ILS_WaitForThreadProc() 
    kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  
    ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart()    
    ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()
```

UPD2: The problem is not with the loop at all, I created the simplest application where I just create a window and a renderer and then return 0, it still gives me a hanging console. Like this:

```
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) return 1;
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 480, 0);
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    return 0;
}
```

Same thing when I destroy them properly. The problem is in the renderer.

UPD3: Here is the [Parallel Stack window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSduJ.png) during the "hanging". There is no "main" thread since I close it successfully, these are the threads which stop the program from closing properly. Other than that, it doesn't give me any understanding of the problem.

Comment: So what does the call stack look like when it hangs? Also result of `SDL_Init` should be checked and event loop should probably be `while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)`.

Comment: Yes, fixed the loop, thanks. Still, has nothing to do with the issue. I know about SDL_Init and so on, I just simplified the code, as it has nothing to do with the issue either. The problem was also present when everything was checked.

Comment: Any other threads blocking on something? You should also tell your IDE to use export symbols so you know the function names of the `ntdll.dll` things.

Comment: Are you sure that this call stack is from the main thread?

Comment: Loaded symbols and updated the callstack. And I'm not sure about the main thread, sorry, this is all I get in the Call Stack window when I pause debugging during the hanging. Moving the PollEvent loop to the end of the main loop didn't change anything.

Comment: Try dropping back to SDL 2.0.8; 2.0.9 has some new joystick handling code that interacts oddly with the event loop on occasion.

Comment: I tried 2.0.5, gave me the same result. The problem is not with the loop at all, I created the simplest application where I just create a window and a renderer and then return 0, it still gives me a hanging console. The problem is in the renderer.

Comment: As for the call stack, what IDE are you using? Visual Studio has a [Parallel Stacks window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-the-parallel-stacks-window?view=vs-2017), which let's you see the stacks for all current threads. Unfortunately that window isn't open per default, but you can find it under _Debug -> Windows -> Parallel Stacks_. Maybe that gives a better overview of your situation.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2013 (because 2017 is too slow), but testing it in 2017 gave the same results. Added the parallel stacks to the post, thank you for telling about the feature.

Comment: Those threads are waiting for something. Either you need to call some extra cleanup method in SDL, or this might be a bug. Could be related to [this bug](https://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4055) maybe?

Comment: You could also try asking on the [SDL forums](https://discourse.libsdl.org/) and come back with any useful information (or potentially the solution) here. _(Answering your own question is more than welcome, just make sure you give proper credit if you found the solution elsewhere.)_

Comment: _(On a side note, you should tag people when you respond in comments, I only checked back on this question because it interests me, otherwise I would not have noticed your update.)_